# sql flag a comparison when value not exist

Tags: sql

I'm looking for an SQL script which can flag values which don't exist in a comparison.

Actually in my table user I have 3 users: johny, sandra, manu.

```sql
select name
from user
where name in ('johny', 'alexander', 'sandra', 'manu', 'pierro')
```

What I want is the request return me 'alexander' and 'pierro'.

I'm on Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but in standard ANSI SQL, I would use a NOT EXISTS with   a VALUES clause:

```
select v.name
from (
   values ('johny'), ('alexander'), ('sandra'), ('manu'), ('pierro')
) as v(name)
where not exists (select *
                  from user u
                  where u.name = v.name);
```

Alternatively you could use `NOT IN` if you are certain that `user.name` never contains a NULL value. But typically `NOT EXISTS` is more efficient anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the list of values and use `not exists` or `left join`.  Here is a typical method:

```
select n.name
from (select 'johny' as name union all
      select 'alexander' as name union all
      select 'sandra' as name union all
      select 'manu' as name union all
      select 'pierro'
     ) n left join
     user u
     on u.name = n.name
where u.name is null;
```

Some databases require a table name in the subquery, such as `from dual` or `sysibm.sysdumm1`.  Many databases also support the standard `VALUES()` derived table constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minus/except` as follows

```
 select name
  from (select 'johny' union all
  select 'alexander' union all
  select 'sandra' union all
  select 'manu'union all
  select 'pierro'
 ) 
 minus
 Select name from user u
```